# How to convert T-SQL that deals with OPENXML, WITH and BIGINT?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to convert a procedure to use in SQL Azure. I first got an error on `OPENXML` saying it's not supported on SQL Azure, then I find out it can be replaced with `nodes`.

But I'm not sure how to convert the `WITH (Id BIGINT '.')` part. I know `WITH` creates a subquery but what is the `'.'` doing here?

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[DocsR]
    @ids    xml     -- <Ids><Id>1</Id><Id>2</Id></Ids>
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @IdsXml xml 
    exec sp_xml_preparedocument @IdsXml OUTPUT, @Ids

    SELECT
        DoctId,
        DocNm
    FROM
        Docs
    WHERE
        --DocId IN (SELECT Id FROM OPENXML(@IdsXml, '/Ids/Id', 2) WITH (Id BIGINT '.'))
          DocId IN (SELECT Id FROM @IdsXml.nodes('/Ids/Id') WITH (Id BIGINT '.'))
END
GO
```

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common 
table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, 
the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

Comment: '.' is an XPath expression referencing the value of the current node. Basically, your query is selecting the value of all /Ids/Id as the column "Id".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
  SELECT
        DoctId,
        DocNm
    FROM
        Docs
    WHERE
          DocId IN (SELECT Id = node.value('.', 'INT') 
                      FROM @IdsXml.nodes('/Ids/Id') AS R(node))
```